# Is it possible to capture internal audio in Swift for iOS applications?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m relatively new to Swift programming and am trying to create an application that involves capturing internal audio. As far as I’m aware it’s impossible to do so in Swift, but was curious if anyone knew of a way. I’d assume even if you figured out how to do this you’d be prevented from uploading to the App Store but I’m still curious anyway. Any advice appreciated

As far as I’m aware AVFoundation only captures audio through the mic so I don’t believe there’s a way to achieve internal audio capture with it.

Answer (score 2):

[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation?language=objc)

Work with audiovisual assets, control device cameras, process audio, and configure system audio interactions.
[System Audio Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/system_audio) Integrate system audio into your app.

Related Documentation
[AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

...from that linked guide:

**At a Glance**

There are two facets to the AVFoundation framework—APIs related to video and APIs related just to audio. The older audio-related classes provide easy ways to deal with audio.

*.* To play sound files, you can use

```
AVAudioPlayer
```

.
To record audio, you can use

```
AVAudioRecorder
```

.
You can also configure the audio behavior of your application using

```
AVAudioSession
```

; this is described in [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875).